# awk + perl + get two arguments in to awk syntax

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell-scripting, awk

please advice what wrong with my awk syntax and how to fix it ( this syntax is in my ksh script ) and I run my script on linux machine

my target is to get from the file.txt only the lines that between the dates:

FROM  **2012-04-19** TO  **2012-04-22**

remark - other solution can be with perl

```
[root@test1 /var/tmp]# a='2012/04/19'
[root@test1 /var/tmp]# b='2012/04/22'
[root@test1 /var/tmp]# awk -v A=$a -v B=$b '/A/,/B/' file.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

file.txt

```
[ 2012/04/18 21:49:01:857 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(): 
[ 2012/04/18 21:50:02:379 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(
[ 2012/04/18 21:57:52:64  ] Monitor::handle_client_message():
[ 2012/04/18 21:57:52:252 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(
[ 2012/04/18 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message():

[ 2012/04/19 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(): 
[ 2012/04/20 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(): 
[ 2012/04/21 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(): 
[ 2012/04/22 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message():
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
$ awk '/2012\/04\/19/,/2012\/04\/22/' file.txt
```

You need to escape the slashes as shown.

**Edit:**

It can be done using variables like:

```
$ a='2012\/04\/19'
$ b='2012\/04\/22'
$ awk "/$a/,/$b/" file.txt
[ 2012/04/19 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(): 
[ 2012/04/20 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(): 
[ 2012/04/21 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message(): 
[ 2012/04/22 21:58:46:958 ] Monitor::handle_client_message():
```

**Edit2:**

Escaping the slashes can be using done `sed` command like:

```
$ a='2012/04/19'
$ aa=$(echo $a | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
$ echo $aa
2012\/04\/19
```

Then, you can `aa` instead of `a`. Similarly, it can be done for `b`.

Comment: yes but I need the arguments they are dynamic and arguments can change - so I need to use in awk the "-v" flag please advice how to do that ?

Comment: @yael: updated my answer.

Comment: yes thx but I dont want to add the "\" in the argument because I take the string as 2012/04/19 from the file.txt , so did you have other solution ?

Comment: @yael the \ is required because it escapes the / which would otherwise act as a delimiter in the awk program. This is very basic stuff that you should really know. Can I suggest that instead of getting SF to do your job for you, you speak to your manager about getting some basic training, that you learn to use man pages, and that you spend some time learning how to solve problems yourself.

Comment: @Khaled thx for your great support

Comment: you may use different separators for sed: `sed 's|/|\/|g'`

Answer (score 2):

The following is the *correct* way to do what you want.

You don't want to have to pre-escape your search patterns and you should use the `-v` option as you show in your question (but the shell variables should be quoted).

When you have patterns in variables, you can't use `//` to surround the patterns - you have to use the match operator `~` (tilde).

This works correctly for your data:

```
a='2012/04/19'
b='2012/04/22'
awk -v A="$a" -v B="$b" '$0 ~ A, $0 ~ B' file.txt
```

The reason you can't put variables inside `//` is that the characters in the name of the variable are seen as the pattern rather than the contents of the variable.

Comment: WOW very cooooooooool